# MongoDB: Cannot add to a Sub-document of a Sub-document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am attempting to use Mongoose to add an entry to the questions array.
However mongoose is saying the data I am accessing is undefined.

```
{"content":
    {"_id":"58c6f76e06e6edda1b000007",
     "name":"testCourse",
     "__v":0,
     "subjects": 
         [{"name":"testSubject",
           "_id":"58c6f85280a5d6591c000007",
           "questions":[]}
         ]
     }
}
```

Here is my method that creates the entry:

```
module.exports.makeQuestion = function(req, res){
    var courseid = req.params.courseid;
    var subjectid = req.params.subjectid;

    console.log("cou:"+ courseid + " sub:"+ subjectid);

    Course.findById(courseid, function(err, course){
      course.subjects.questions.push({question: req.params.question,
                                      answer:req.params.answer})
      sendJSONResponse(res, 200, course);
    });
}
```

What error am I making when adding the entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `course.subjects` is an array. So it doesn't know which of the subdocuments you want to push the object to. To solve this you could do `course.subjects.id(_id).questions.push(question)` which should work if you know the ID of the subdocument-object. Else you have to loop through the array to find the one that you're looking for.